# awk compare files, insert character in case of mismatch

Tags: awk

I have two tab-delimited files.

pos.txt

```
A   100027454       
A   100028517       
A   100028954       
A   100028986       
A   100033307       
A   100033331       
A   100033338       
A   100033382       
A   100033410       
A   100033424
```

and

file1.txt

```
A   102470  T       *
A   102471  G       *
A   102472  C       *
A   102473  T       *
A   102474  G       *
A   102475  G       *
A   102476  T       *
A   102477  C       *
A   102478  C       *
A   102479  T       *
```

I want to compare the two files on the basis of the second column in the first file. If the second column value exists in a row in both files I want it to output the entire row in the second file. If the value is present in the first file and not in the second file I want it to output an `X` in the fourth column and the first three columns as is.

This is as far as I have been able to get:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]++;next}a[$2]' pos.txt file1.txt
```

but this only prints column 2 values that it finds in `file1`. I don't want these values to be lost.

Comment: Could you add your desired output to complement your problem description?

Comment: There is no 4th column in the first file so what exactly is it you're trying to output with the X in the 4th column? Why not post an example where some of the fields from pos.txt DO match and the associated desired output? That would help clarify your requirements quite a bit - right now it's completely vague. Even naming your `first file` as `pos.txt` and `second file` as `file1` instead of simply `file1` and `file2` is obfuscating. Just make your question clear and simple.

Answer (score 0):

This will meet your needs:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]++;next}a[$2]{$4="\tx";print;next}1' pos.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: Hey. This helps a lot on the logic front but the code doesnt exactly do what i need it to. I need it to print X only for column values present in pos.txt i dont want it to print everything in file1.txt